# Updating Jquery Datatables Rows

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I'm using jQuery datatables to display quite a lot of measurement-data from various ventilation and temperature sensors. The data is aquired via webservices and since the amount of data per table is growing i would like to display only the changes in the datatable and not repopulate it when something has changed. The data is delivered via JSON Object and i wonder if there is way of figuring out which item (out of hundreds measurement items) has changed quickly. Of course i can iterate through every array-row and every array value but it seems that this is not the best way to do it. i've got no problem to compare each an every element but maybe there is a way where two similar arrays (equal length, almost equal data) can be subtracted from each other? some library or so? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should edit your webservice, so that you parse in 2 datetime variables. That way you can get the "new" sensor data in between the two datetimes. When then calling you webservice you simply set the "currentTime" and "lastCheck".

Comment: i thought i could leave it as it is just because it's fast enough to process the data inside the browser environment ... although it might not be the best way. thanks!